# Printing very faint lines on a laser printer

Tags: print-design

I do want to draw a grid of very faint equally spaced parallel lines on my b/w printer. I created PDFs with different methods (via a Python module / via Inkscape) but they all had the same problem:

- Making the lines thinner just resulted in larger (noticeable) and inconsistent spaces between the "printer dots" i.e. some lines look solid, others look dotted.
- If I on the other hand defined a lighter hue of gray as a colour, the lines got indeed fainter, but only ever fourth line or so actually got printed. (Probably due to an aliasing effect.)

How would you go about printing very faint lines considering these problems?

(I hope this is within the scope of this site, I did not find any better suited SE.)

Comment: You need to know quite much about the technical specifications of your printer to accomplish this. Most likely you need to write direct printer control code. You up to the task? Is this a postscript printer (i would guess not).

Comment: So is it correct that pdfs are not really a good way to accurately "tell the printer what to do"?  What characterises *postscript printer*? (My printer is a Samsung ML-3310ND) Can you recommend any references for further reading on that? I think it would be worth diving somewhat more into that topic.

Comment: PDF is device neutral so it does not know where the actual dots are going to lie. You need to hit the native resolution of the printer otherwise you will get the lines in between 2 samples this can result in missing/double wide or dashed line, due to aliasation. In general the idea behind modern printers is that you should not care, but in this case you do care.

Comment: @joojaa I know this is an old question; I'm having basically the same issue except I used InDesign to create the grid. I've been trying to change downsampling settings in InDesign, but it doesn't seem to work. So the only way is to write some code?

Comment: @IrvineWizards lets put it this way: I have never seen anybody who didnt do this directly with printer language succeed. But it is possible that a RIP can have this feature. A commercial printer can thus have a way to offer this as a service.

Comment: @joojaa I see. So probably all I can do is play around with the file to minimize this flaw. Or take it to a professional printer. (Or learn to code it, but I think that'll be beyond my capabilities.) Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the meantime I talked to a professional, who confirmed that with many usual consumer printers the best option is just trial and error to get the best result, and that they often also aren't very consistent over time. Professional printing machines apparently often have multiple different shades gray as inks/toners which allow for more detailed prints.